# Как сделать фабрику с отношениями?

Tags: laravel

Как мне сгенерировать тестовые данные с отношениями через seederы и фабрики? Мне нужно создать несколько пользователей с постами, у которых будут комментарии. Я покажу только один seeder, потому что у меня они все одинаковые.

```
class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => $this->faker->password()
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
            'admin' => 0,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the model's email address should be unverified.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
     */
    public function unverified()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'email_verified_at' => null,
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

```
public function run()
    {
        $users = User::factory()->count(5)->create();
    }
```

```
class PostFactory extends Factory{

    public function definition(){
        return [
        'user_id' => ,
        'category_id' => ,
        'title' => $this->faker->realText(rand(25, 30)),
        'slug' => $this->faker->password() ,
        'image' => null ,
        'content' => $this->faker->realText(rand(200, 300)),
        'published_by' => true ,
        'created_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-60 days', '-30 days'),
        'updated_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-20 days', '-1 days'),
        ];
    }
}
```

```
class CommentFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'post_id' => 
            'user_id' => 
            'published_by' => true
            'content' => $this->faker->paragraph();
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-relationships - has, for

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать фабрику постов такой:

```php
class PostFactory extends Factory {
    public function definition() {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::pluck('id')[$this->faker->numberBetween(1, User::count())],
            'category_id' => Category::pluck('id')[$this->faker->numberBetween(1, Category::count())],
            'title' => $this->faker->realText(rand(25, 30)),
            'slug' => $this->faker->password() ,
            'image' => null ,
            'content' => $this->faker->realText(rand(200, 300)),
            'published_by' => true ,
            'created_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-60 days', '-30 days'),
            'updated_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-20 days', '-1 days'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Фабрику комментариев такой:

```php
class CommentFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'post_id' => Post::pluck('id')[$this->faker->numberBetween(1, Post::count())],
            'user_id' => User::pluck('id')[$this->faker->numberBetween(1, User::count())],
            'published_by' => true,
            'content' => $this->faker->paragraph()
        ];
    }
}
```

И именно в такой последовательности настроить создание моделей:

```php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
         User::factory(10)->create();
         Category::factory(10)->create();
         Post::factory(10)->create();
         Comment::factory(10)->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне выдает ошибку : ErrorException 

  Undefined offset: 0

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php:1623
      +1 vendor frames 
  2   database/factories/CategoryFactory.php:21
      Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetGet()
      +6 vendor frames 
  9   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\{closure}()